# CheckBoxListComboBox unseelct the selection programatically

Tags: java, swing

I am using com.jidesoft.combobox.CheckBoxListComboBox

I made the selection of the checkboxes programatically with

```
     int[] indecesToSelect =..

     combo.setSelectedIndices(indecesToSelect);
```

But i dont see any way to unselect any selection.

I tried

```
     combo.setSelectedItem(item, false);
```

But this is not unselecting , this is also selecting

Also tried

```
     combo.getList().clearSelection();
```

no effect

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);` to unselect.
[Source](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/combobox/MultiSelectListComboBox.html#setSelectedIndex(int))

Comment: perfect , thank you!